# Bootstrap 3: Tabs: How to create an 'all' tab that shows all content?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm working with Bootstrap 3, and I want to add an 'all' tab that will show the content of all other individual tabs.
I've 3 tabs in total.
'Ongoing': displaying ongoing projects.
'Completed': displaying completed projects.
'Renovated': displaying renovated projects.
Now, I'm trying to add an 'All' tab that will show all the projects.

We already have [an answer for the same to achieve in Bootstrap 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16302460/2733146). But it doesn't seem to apply for Bootstrap 3. Kindly check the output of bootply in the above linked answer. That is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li><a id="tabAll" href="#">All</a></li>
      <li class="active">
          <a href="#on" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            Ongoing
          </a>
      </li>
       <li>
          <a href="#com" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              Completed
          </a>
      </li>
       <li>
          <a href="#ren" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
               Renovated
          </a>
      </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="on">
          <h2>Ongoing</h2>

      </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="com">
          <h2>Completed</h2>

      </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ren">
          <h2>Renovated</h2>

      </div>
</div>

$('#tabAll').on('click',function(){
  $('#tabAll').parent().addClass('active');  
  $('.tab-pane').addClass('active in');  
  $('[data-toggle="tab"]').parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wxgthtw/)

Comment: thanks man, that worked!
Is there a way to make a specific tab active and load it's contents on page load?

Comment: You can give an active class to the intended li and its section. Like if you see the example the #on is given active class.

Comment: sorry, I think my question wasn't accurate.
specific means based on the url, the active tab should vary. something like mypage.html#com should show completed and mypage.html#ren show renovated projects.

Comment: You can trigger the anchor href by taking the `window.location.hash` on page load

Comment: why not `<a id="tabAll" data-toggle="tab" href=".tab-content.tab-pane">`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this example right here: https://www.bootply.com/60331
js code:

```
$('#tabAll').click(function(){
  $('#tabAll').addClass('active');  
  $('.tab-pane').each(function(i,t){
    $('#myTabs li').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active');  
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tabbable" id="myTabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a id="tabAll">All</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 3.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Also you can do it by less code: 

.nav-tabs>li>a').tab('show');

- This code will show all tabs

Comment: Edit question and add this on question